# How do I pattern match on a Cmd msg inside a Test API module?

Tags: elm

How do I pattern match on a Cmd msg inside a Test API module?

I have a Test API that serves as an alternative to a web service.

```
sources : Id -> (Result Http.Error (List Source) -> msg) -> Cmd msg
sources profileId msg =
    [ { platform = "WordPress", username = "bizmonger", linksFound = 0 }
    , { platform = "YouTube", username = "bizmonger", linksFound = 0 }
    , { platform = "StackOverflow", username = "scott-nimrod", linksFound = 0 }
    ]
        |> Result.Ok
        |> msg
        |> Task.succeed
        |> Task.perform identity
```

**Issue:**

I receive a compile error for the code below:

```
addSource : Id -> Source -> (Result Http.Error (List Source) -> msg) -> Cmd msg
addSource profileId source msg =
    let
        result =
            sources profileId msg
    in
        case result of
            Ok sources ->
                (source :: sources)
                    |> Result.Ok
                    |> msg
                    |> Task.succeed
                    |> Task.perform identity

            Err _ ->
                Cmd.none
```

> Ok sources ->  ^^^^^^^^^^ The pattern matches things of type:
>
> ```
> Result error value
> ```
>
> But the values it will actually be trying to match are:
>
> ```
> Cmd msg
> ```

**Note:**

I understand that these functions return a Cmd msg and that I need to pattern match on a Cmd msg. However, this code is in a TestAPI module and not a typical UI module. Thus, I don't think I should have to define a discriminated union for various messages that have already been defined in the UI client that relies on this TestAPI module.

**Appendix:**

```
type alias Source =
    { platform : String, username : String, linksFound : Int }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is about "mocking" an API endpoint, I'll refrain from my usual "don't box data in a command if you're not triggering side-effects" spiel.

Instead, let me propose splitting up your `sources` function:

```
sourceData : List Source
sourceData =
    [ { platform = "WordPress", username = "bizmonger", linksFound = 0 }
    , { platform = "YouTube", username = "bizmonger", linksFound = 0 }
    , { platform = "StackOverflow", username = "scott-nimrod", linksFound = 0 }
    ]


mockResponse : a -> (Result Http.Error a -> msg) -> Cmd msg
mockResponse data tagger =
    Result.Ok data
        |> Task.succeed
        |> Task.perform tagger


sources : Id -> (Result Http.Error (List Source) -> msg) -> Cmd msg
sources profileId msg =
    mockResponse sourceData msg
```

Now, implementing your `addSource` function becomes a reasonably simple call like so:

```
addSource : Id -> Source -> (Result Http.Error (List Source) -> msg) -> Cmd msg
addSource profileId source msg 
    mockResponse (source :: sourceData) msg
```

Comment: Yea.. That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a realization that I'm still doing functional programming.
Thus, why not compose functions together from core essentials to more involved.

Thus, I did the following:

```
addSourceBase : Id -> Source -> List Source
addSourceBase profileId source =
    source :: (profileId |> sourcesBase)


addSource : Id -> Source -> (Result Http.Error (List Source) -> msg) -> Cmd msg
addSource profileId source msg =
    source
        |> addSourceBase profileId
        |> Result.Ok
        |> msg
        |> Task.succeed
        |> Task.perform identity
```